# xcode 6 drawing line error

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

Hi everyone i am making a sprite-kit app in which the user must be able to draw multiple lines. To do this I made the following code.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var line = SKShapeNode()
    var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    var touch: UITouch!
    var location:CGPoint!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch!
        location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        drawLine()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        self.delete(line)
    }

    func drawLine() {

        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, location.x, location.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 500.0, 500.0)

        line.path = path
        line.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
        line.lineWidth = 5.0
        self.addChild(line)

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

This works but when the users tries the draw the second line the application crashes.
Can someone explain to me why that is happening?

***------Edit------***

I think i need to use an array of lines so I did something like this:

`var line: [[SKShapeNode]] = []`

which gives me the following error:
[[SKShapeNode]] does not have a member named 'path'.
So I though I had to make the path variable an array as well but that only gave me a second error: GameScene does not have a member named 'path'. So I changed it all back but I still think I have to use an array although I can't really figure out how to make it work.

Comment: You're adding the same node (line) twice when you call drawLine a second time. You must create a new SKShapeNode instance whenever you call drawLine if you want both drawn, or just change the line's path to update the existing line's path.

Comment: So the best way to do this is by using arrays but how do I implement this?

Comment: Your exploration into the world of understanding arrays, is not the subject of this question. Google "Swift Arrays"  - the internets are your friend. :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this..now you'll redefine your line every time

```
  import SpriteKit

    class GameScene: SKScene {

        var line = SKShapeNode()
        var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
        var touch: UITouch!
        var location:CGPoint!

        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        }

        override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
            /* Called when a touch begins */
            touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch!
            location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            drawLine()
        }

        override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
            self.delete(line)
        }

        func drawLine() {

            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, location.x, location.y)
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 500.0, 500.0)

            SKShapeNode *line = [SKShapeNode node]; //redfine line every time 
            line.path = path
            line.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
            line.lineWidth = 5.0
            self.addChild(line)

        }

        override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
            /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        }
    }
```